# Need to copy feature file to some location before execution of test cases in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

There is some specified location where feature files are present. There is need to copy these files to

```
src/test/resources/
```

before execution of test cases as a part of automation.

I tried using

```
@BeforeClass
//java code to do copying of files from one location to other
```

But Cucumber scans all feature files in the first place. So, it is failing as not finding any feature files which is mentioned under

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/subscription.feature")
```

Comment: How are u executing these tests? Maven?

Comment: yes... using maven

Answer (score 0):

Use the `maven resources plugin` in the `validate phase` to copy the feature files. [Link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html), Change the `outputDirectory` and `resource directory` as per your configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <!-- Destination folder -->     
         <outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\test\resources\features</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                    <!-- Source folder -->
                    <directory>E:\.....\nonresource</directory>
                    </resource>
               </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```